# Google transit data feed into Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

HI,
    My client want to implement directions on google map (googletransitdata) with rails application. i have not how to do that. i didn't work with Google API's so far. i don't know how to proceed ... can any one help me regarding this. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API for Google Transit unfortunately.  You could probably scrape the output but this would likely violate Google's Terms of Service.

There are a few Transit authorities who provide APIs - if you want to cover a very specific area you might be able to go direct.  Have a look at [Programmable Web's Travel category](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Travel).

Comment: depends a lot on your application and which api you use.  Here is an article on connecting to a different api with rails, you may be able to adapt it, depending on which api you choose: http://blog.thembid.com/2007/07/12/using-the-digg-api-with-ruby-on-rails/